# Returning a null to zero mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

i have my query like these:

```
SELECT tbl_clinics.clinic_name, COALESCE(SUM(tbl_bill.bill_amt),0) AS
 clinic_tot FROM tbl_clinics LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_check_up ON 
tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_check_up.clinic_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_bill ON 
tbl_check_up.bill_id = tbl_bill.bill_id WHERE tbl_clinics.user_id = 102;
```

Here, my query returns only these:

Clinic A = 800.00

Clinic B = 500.00

i want to return my clinic_name and the sum of the bill from it, also i want to include clinic_name and a sum of null or if it is null, then it will return 0

something like this output:

Clinic A = 800.00

Clinic B = 500.00

Clinic C = 0

Clinic D = 0

Here is my table structure:

[image]

Comment: `SELECT tbl_clinics.clinic_name, IFNULL(SUM(tbl_bill.bill_amt),0) AS
     clinic_tot FROM tbl_clinics LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_check_up ON 
    tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_check_up.clinic_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_bill ON 
   tbl_check_up.bill_id = tbl_bill.bill_id WHERE tbl_clinics.user_id = 102` both working same.Can you provide us sample data?

Comment: @SagarGangwal there at the top Clinic A = 800.00

Clinic B = 500.00.. thats my sample data

Comment: This is output which you want.I want input data,on which you execute this query and that return specified Output.

Comment: @SagarGangwal thats the output sir, the first in top is the output, the second is what i want where it has Clinic C = 0 and Clinic D = 0

Comment: Just put input data.

Comment: `SELECT tbl_clinics.clinic_name, IFNULL(SUM(tbl_bill.bill_amt),0) AS clinic_tot FROM tbl_clinics LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_check_up ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_check_up.clinic_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_bill ON tbl_check_up.bill_id = tbl_bill.bill_id WHERE tbl_clinics.user_id = 102` This query works fine.

Comment: yes sir, it works fine.. but it doesn't output what i want, where i want null to be zero, but the zero or null values doesn't came out

Something like

Clinic A = 100.00
Clinic B = 200.00
Clinic C = 0
Clinic D = 0

Comment: It came out.I had tried this one.It's give output with 0 as total bill.